# How to find Percent Frequency gg plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

There have been a few questions on here asking how to plot percent frequency. I have tried implementing the suggestions but am still having trouble.

I have the following vector:

```
var <- c(2,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,3,2,3,3,5,1,4,4,0,3,4,1,0,3,3,0,0,
     1,3,2,6,2,2,2,1,0,2,3,2,0,0,0,0,3,2,2,4,3,2,2,0,4,1,0,1,3,1,4,3,1,2,
     6,7,6,1,2,2,4,5,3,0,6,5,2,0,7,1,7,3,1,4,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,4,2,0,3,3,2,2,2,5,3,2,5,2,5)
```

I plotted a histogram using the following code:

```
df <- data.table(x = var)

df <- df[, .N, by=x]

df$x <- factor(df$x, levels=c(0:25))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y= N)) +
     geom_bar(
     stat="identity", width=1.0, 
     colour = "darkgreen",
     fill = 'paleturquoise4'
    )

p <- p + labs(scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) )

p = p + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 50)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 50, 2))

print(p)
```

I tried using the following but it does not work.

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y= N)) +
     geom_bar(
     aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),
     stat="identity", width=1.0, 
     colour = "darkgreen",
     fill = 'paleturquoise4'
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is that you can do the calculation before you draw the graphic. But, if I follow your approach, you would want something like this.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = N/sum(N)), stat="identity", width=1.0, 
    colour = "dark green", fill = 'paleturquoise4') +
    ylab("y")
```

[image]